# The server cannot handle directory requests when trying to validate domain credentials

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, ldap, windows-server

We have an MVC app running in IIS on a Windows Server 2012 R2 OS that uses the domain accounts to validate user access. This works for most servers except one customer set up. We get the generic "The server cannot handle directory requests" during the PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials. The IIS app pool uses a domain user that has admin rights to the local server to execute all transactions.

To narrow down what's causing the issue, we've ported to code to a winforms app, and a powershell script. We logged in to the machine as the domain user used in the app pool and ran both programs. Both returned the same error.

However, when we logged in to the server using a domain admin, the exception is no longer thrown and we are able to validate against the AD.

We just want to know what could be causing this behavior. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the powershell script we made:

```
$UserName = "Foo"
$Password = "Bar"
$Domain = "mydomain"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$DS = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext('domain',$Domain)
$DS.ValidateCredentials($UserName, $Password)
```

[image: App Pool Configurations]

Comment: Can you show us your config for your app pool?

Comment: Hi, which part of the app pool config? Can I export the app pool configuration on IIS?

Comment: show us everything you can, also show us your .net authorization rules in IIS. Not sure about exporting though.

Comment: The only authorization rule in the IIS website is it allows all users

Comment: I've edited the post and added a picture of the app pool config

Comment: Look at your application pool IDentity. Its `stddomain\admin` Change that to network service or or applicationpoolidentity

Comment: Hi, We need that to be a specific user to enable windows authentication for SQL Server. 

Also I just wanted to point out that the same set up works with a multitude of other customer servers except for a single customer set up. 

Also, like I said in the description, taking the code outside of IIS returns the same exception so I changing the identity used by the app pool should return the same issue.

Comment: Sorry that's all the suggestions I have, these types of problems are rather hard to debug on my end if I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: Does this organization restrict which computers users can logon to? (in AD Users and Computers, it's the "Log On To..." button on the Account tab) I'm talking about not just the service account you use for the app pool, but everyone who will be authenticating to the website.

Comment: In addition to account-based logon restrictions (previous comment), has "log on locally" been restricted on the server through either a local policy or domain-based group policy? I've run into this when companies want to run IIS on their DC (not my idea, yes it is a terrible idea) because 'domain users' do not generally have 'log on locally' permission on DCs. Works fine for domain admins -- because **they** are in the log on locally list.